# Is there a way to enable Spring-Boot to reveal more information about 'BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name'?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have been working with Spring for 8 years now, and very often I run into this exception.

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
```

For example, I am working on a service right now that fails to start because a Bean requires a connection to Azure (on AMQP port) to be successful.   The stack trace says nothing about the cause of the error though.   Enabling `com.azure.core` or `org.apache.http` logging DEBUG also not helping.

Is it possible to intercept the Bean instantiation to reveal more information about the cause of the error?   Is there a Spring coding pattern for this kind of thing?

Would love to solve this once and for all so that users of services I create are never confused about a Bean loading exception.

This page elaborates on the issue: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-beancreationexception  but never tells you what to do when dealing with Beans being loaded from a 3rd party lib rather than your own code.